# can I use different hints in one clause of union in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hint

I have a merge query of below format -

```
merge into dest 
using (select /*+ use_hash(t1,t2) parallel (4)*/ t1_name ,count(*) from table1 , table2 on t1.col=t2.col
group by  t1_name) src
on (values)
when matched then update dest.col
```

now I have to do union in this query

```
merge into dest 
using (select count(*),t1_name from (select /*+ use_hash(t1,t2) parallel (4)*/ t1_name ,count(*) from table1 , table2 on t1.col=t2.col
group by  t1_name
union all
select t1_name,count(*) from table t1 group by t1_name from table t1  group by t1_name ) group by t1_name) src
on (values)
when matched then update dest.col
```

My question is do I have to give parallel hint in second union clause also . Also use_hash hint which was running good earlier would not have impact on adding union clause in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hints apply to each select independently. First, you need to understand how parallel execution works in terms of session level and/or hints applied.

In this you have three elements

- The merge statement itself which will update some rows and will not run in parallel
- The first data set recover with the first select will run in parallel
- The second will run in parallel because of the hints applied to the first statement

I am assuming the tables are configured with noparallel and that you are not enabling parallel dml. I won't even try to replicate the query, because I don't know exactly what you want to do with it.

Test case

```
SQL> create table t1 ( c1 number, c2 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> create table t2 ( c1 number, c3 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2  begin
  3  for i in 1 .. 10000
  4  loop
  5   insert into t1 values ( i , dbms_random.value );
  6   insert into t2 values ( i , dbms_random.value );
  7  end loop;
  8* end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2  begin
  3  for i in 1 .. 10000
  4  loop
  5   insert into t1 values ( i , dbms_random.value );
  6  end loop;
  7* end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from t1 ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     20000

SQL> select count(*) from t2 ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     10000
```

Now I am going to build a merge statement to update the table t2 using a source based on a union select. Forget in this case the meaning of the query, which has no sense at all, but the resulting execution plan

```
SQL> merge into t dest
  2  using ( select distinct t1 from (
  3  select /*+ use_hash(t2,t1) parallel (4)*/ t1.c1 as t1 from t1 inner join t2 on ( t1.c1=t2.c1)
  4  union all
  5  select t2.c1 as t1 from t1 inner join t2 on ( t1.c1=t2.c1 )
  6   ))  src on ( src.t1 = dest.c1 )
  7* when matched then update set dest.c2 = dbms_random.value

10000 rows merged.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 889987475

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | MERGE STATEMENT                     |          | 10000 |   253K|    43   (3)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  MERGE                              | T        |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR                    |          |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)              | :TQ10006 | 10000 |   498K|    43   (3)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,06 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   4 |     VIEW                            |          |       |       |            |          |  Q1,06 | PCWP |            |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                      |          | 10000 |   498K|    43   (3)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,06 | PCWP |            |
|   6 |       PX RECEIVE                    |          | 10000 |   126K|    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,06 | PCWP |            |
|   7 |        PX SEND BROADCAST            | :TQ10005 | 10000 |   126K|    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,05 | P->P | BROADCAST  |
|   8 |         VIEW                        |          | 10000 |   126K|    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |          HASH UNIQUE                |          | 10000 |   126K|    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|  10 |           PX RECEIVE                |          | 10000 |   126K|    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,05 | PCWP |            |
|  11 |            PX SEND HASH             | :TQ10004 | 10000 |   126K|    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | P->P | HASH       |
|  12 |             HASH UNIQUE             |          | 10000 |   126K|    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  13 |              VIEW                   |          | 40000 |   507K|    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  14 |               UNION-ALL             |          |       |       |            |          |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|* 15 |                HASH JOIN            |          | 20000 |   507K|     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  16 |                 PX RECEIVE          |          | 10000 |   126K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  17 |                  PX SEND HASH       | :TQ10000 | 10000 |   126K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | P->P | HASH       |
|  18 |                   PX BLOCK ITERATOR |          | 10000 |   126K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|  19 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T2       | 10000 |   126K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|  20 |                 PX RECEIVE          |          | 20000 |   253K|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  21 |                  PX SEND HASH       | :TQ10001 | 20000 |   253K|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,01 | P->P | HASH       |
|  22 |                   PX BLOCK ITERATOR |          | 20000 |   253K|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|  23 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1       | 20000 |   253K|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|* 24 |                HASH JOIN            |          | 20000 |   507K|     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  25 |                 PX RECEIVE          |          | 10000 |   126K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  26 |                  PX SEND HASH       | :TQ10002 | 10000 |   126K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,02 | P->P | HASH       |
|  27 |                   PX BLOCK ITERATOR |          | 10000 |   126K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,02 | PCWC |            |
|  28 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T2       | 10000 |   126K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,02 | PCWP |            |
|  29 |                 PX RECEIVE          |          | 20000 |   253K|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,04 | PCWP |            |
|  30 |                  PX SEND HASH       | :TQ10003 | 20000 |   253K|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | P->P | HASH       |
|  31 |                   PX BLOCK ITERATOR |          | 20000 |   253K|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWC |            |
|  32 |                    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1       | 20000 |   253K|     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  33 |       PX BLOCK ITERATOR             |          | 94911 |  3522K|    26   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,06 | PCWC |            |
|  34 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL            | T        | 94911 |  3522K|    26   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,06 | PCWP |            |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("SRC"."T1"="DEST"."C1")
  15 - access("T1"."C1"="T2"."C1")
  24 - access("T1"."C1"="T2"."C1")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - Degree of Parallelism is 4 because of hint
   - PDML is disabled in current session
```

The most important parts of the execution plan below:

- As the tables has no statistics, Oracle has used dynamic sampling.
- The degree used in 4 due to the hing.
- Parallel DML is not enabled at session level, therefore the update resulting of the merge runs in noparallel.
- Oracle builds an VIEW dynamically to join the two datasets of the union, as a result of one of them is running in parallel, the CBO runs in parallel the second one even though it has no hints.
- In a USE_HASH hint use always as driving table the smaller table. Normally the CBO will always do that, so I would recommend to carefully use the USE_HASH hint, because if the smaller table grows to a point that is even greater than the second one, your hint will produce a lot of performance degradation.

Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for the quick explaination . As you said to be careful for for use_hash hint , i want to ask that how the  driving table is  derived . Wont it be derived automatically according to the number of rows present at that time in the table.The order of driving table is defined in hint  use_hash(t1,t2)??how the order is defined. Also I have edited the query missed to add outer query. SO still my query is good or do you suggest any changes. Shall I use parallel in outer query instead of inner?

Comment: @neha, if you collect statistics properly,  Oracle will choose the driving table based on several factors ( not rows ) as  size and cardinality. If the tables are with statistics up-to-date, Oracle will rarely make an error in selecting the driving table. Size is what matters in order to create the hash table. Please, don't forget to upvote the answer if it helped you.

Comment: ok , did you check my edited query ?shall i do parallel in outer instead of inner ? would it make any performance better or bad ? also to have best performance shall i also use parallel in merge ?

Comment: as a good practice, to avoid issues, put the hint paralle(4) in each select statement with the same degree. It won't make any difference in your case, though, because of the view constructed by the CBO in runtime. However, if your merge is updating a lot of records, perhaps you need to put  `merge /*+ parallel(dest,4) */ into dest` . Another thing, DML parallel won't work no matter what if your table has triggers.

Comment: understood, as my merge is updating approx 10 records i wont need parallel there then. -merge into dest 
using (select /*+ parallel (4)*/count(*),t1_name from (select /*+ use_hash(t1,t2) */ t1_name ,count(*) from table1 , table2 on t1.col=t2.col
group by  t1_name
union all
select t1_name,count(*) from table t1 group by t1_name from table t1  group by t1_name ) group by t1_name) src
on (values)
when matched then update dest.col ........so in above query shall i use parallel only in outer  and removed from inner?

Comment: in that case, you don't need it. It will degrade for this amount of rows instead of improve ;)

Comment: Great Thanks :) one more to ask -merge into dest 
using (select /*+ parallel (4)*/count(*),t1_name from (select /*+ use_hash(t1,t2) */ t1_name ,count(*) from table1 , table2 on t1.col=t2.col
group by  t1_name
union all
select t1_name,count(*) from table t1 group by t1_name from table t1  group by t1_name ) group by t1_name) src
on (values)
when matched then update dest.col ........I misssed outer query so in above query shall i use parallel only in outer  and removed from inner

Comment: No, use it in the inner query, it is evaluated first. My advice, put the hint in all selects, then you won't have any issue. The hints which are not considered are treated as comments by the CBO.

Comment: ok so my final query would be -merge into dest 
using (select count(*),t1_name from (select /*+ use_hash(t1,t2) parallel(4) */ t1_name ,count(*) from table1 , table2 on t1.col=t2.col
group by  t1_name
union all
select  /*+ parallel(4) t1_name,count(*) from table t1 group by t1_name from table t1  group by t1_name ) group by t1_name) src  (my second union clause is having one one table so use hash is not applicable)
.....

Comment: now it is ok. you put the hints in the two queries that belong to the union. the outer query is just a view built by the CBO to join both datasets, so nothing to add there.